# Pong game with graphics class and inheritance issue

Tags: eclipse, inheritance, graphics, pong

I've got this lab for a class that creates a pong-like game and I've put the `.java` files for this lab accordingly on pastebin at the following links:

`Ball.java`: http://pastebin.com/VMg75i8U

`Block.java`: http://pastebin.com/T7GCTh4z

`BallTestTwo.java`: http://pastebin.com/gZgR8d2J

`Tester.java`: http://pastebin.com/fG5f5zZR

`Locatable.java`: http://pastebin.com/GE77PLJk

My issue is that I've got the blocks working just fine, as in I can run `Tester.java` with the ball line commented out and get my desired result. However, when I run it with the ball line uncommented, I get errors and just a blank white canvas.

Here are links to word docs of the lab descriptions if you need clarification on what the end result should be. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ifaCiEZgtcTVFPX0t2Mzhzczg/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ifaCiEZgtcMFVWYXIxdjZsdDQ/edit?usp=sharing

**EDIT**
The errors I'm receiving are these forever repeated until I force terminate the program:

```
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BallTestTwo.paint(BallTestTwo.java:42)
    at BallTestTwo.update(BallTestTwo.java:37)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?  What line of code is executing when the error occurs?  What have you tried to fix the problem?  What is the minimal amount of code that causes the error you encounter?  Also, what have your labmates said about it? The internet can definitely solve your problem, but we're not taking this class; you are.

Comment: the lines of code that eclipse is pointing out is lines 37 and 42 in `BallTestTwo.java`.... these were already there when I first opened the file.

As for labmates, it's usually single-person labs and I didn't hit this issue until I started working through the lab at home

Comment: AS for what I've tried, I've done everything I can logically think of and don't see why it would be producing issues like this

Comment: New question, in my `BallTestTwo.java`, I've instantiated a new `Ball` as the comments ask but I'm unsure of what it wants from the "thoroughly test Ball" and  "test all constructors" comments